# Как избежать увеличения нагрузки на сервер заменой js файла пользователя и критично ли это?

Tags: javascript, сокет

Допустим у меня есть js файл, который каждые 20 секунд делает socket.emit('getData'), и в ответ получает data, но пользователь может заменить js файл и сделать этот запрос не каждые 20 секунд, а каждые 0.5, может ли это положить сервер и критично ли это?

Comment: Сокеты устанавливают "единый канал" на время, они не открывают его каждые 20 с или 5 мс, они просто ответ отправляют.. Это уже достаточно оптимизированный вариант... Мне более интересно что означает `пользователь может заменить js файл`.. Да вы смелый человек, раз даёте пользователям "играть" с js файлами

Comment: А как не давать играть с файлами?

Comment: Вы в интернете. Тут в любой момент к вам может прийти любое количество запросов любого вида и неважно какой таймер у вас стоит в js.